# how to import csv file into oracle temp table by plsql

Tags: csv, plsql, import

I' like to import csv data file into oracle temptable.
I'm using oracle 12c and windows.

I write sql like

```
  CREATE global temporary TABLE temp_csv (
  table_name varchar2(100),
  edit_kind varchar2(10)
);

SQLLDR username/password@test, CONTROL=importcsv.CTL

select * from temp_csv;
```

importcsv.CTL is

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\test\tableName.csv'
INTO TABLE temp_csv
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(table_name,edit_kind)
```

is there any idea to import csv data by plsql execution

Comment: A temp table only holds data for the duration of the transaction or session, so loading with SQL*Loader would not be useful. If the data is on the database server or accessible from it then you could use an [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, try this.

Your file's location must be this:  csv_dir/yourfile.csv
You need to specify the columns.

```
drop table csv_test_table;

CREATE TABLE csv_test_table (
  COLUMN1 varchar2(255),
  COLUMN2 varchar2(255),
  COLUMN3 varchar2(255),
  COLUMN4 varchar2(255)

)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY csv_dir
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    records delimited BY newline
    skip 1
    fields 
    terminated BY ',' optionally enclosed BY '"'
    lrtrim
    missing field VALUES are NULL
  )
  LOCATION ('yourfile.csv')  
);
```